# How to bundle static library into NSIS plugin

Tags: c++, c, nsis

I'm new in NSIS and C++.
I write a NSIS plugin to check a license with http request with VS2010.
But the plugin only work on the computers with VS2010 installed.
I guess the reason is the libraries like "ws2_32.lib" is not bundled in the package.
I want the installation package with this plugin worked on the computers without C++ installed.
Is there any idea how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.
Here is my code.

```
    // dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;
    #include <string.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "./../nsis/pluginapi.h"
    #include <windows.h>  
    #include <Wincrypt.h>  
    #pragma comment(lib,"crypt32")  
    #pragma comment(lib,"./../nsis/pluginapi-x86-unicode.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

    void __declspec(dllexport) myFunction(HWND hwndParent, int string_size,
        TCHAR *variables, stack_t **stacktop,
        extra_parameters *extra)
    {
        g_hwndParent = hwndParent;
     
        EXDLL_INIT();
        
        //读取输入参数
        WCHAR szComponent[256];
        popstring(szComponent);
     
        //打印参数
        WCHAR buf[1024];
        //这里能正确打印出来自NSIS的中文信息。
        //wsprintf(buf, L"kagula $0=[%s][szComponent]\n", szComponent);
        //MessageBoxW(g_hwndParent, buf, 0, MB_OK);
    
        WCHAR urlComponent[256];
        popstring(urlComponent);
        //wsprintf(buf, L"kagula $0=[%s][urlComponent]\n", urlComponent);
        //MessageBoxW(g_hwndParent, buf, 0, MB_OK);
    
        WCHAR ipComponent[256];
        popstring(ipComponent);
    
        WCHAR portComponent[256];
        popstring(portComponent);
    
     
        //准备返回参考
    
        int len = (int)wcslen(szComponent);
        int input_len = (int)wcslen(szComponent);
        //printf("%d\n", input_len);
        //char server_id[256];
        //for (int i = 0; i <
        char* server_id = wchar2char(szComponent);
        printf("%d\n", strlen(server_id));
        //char* server_id = new char(256);
        //for (int i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        //  server_id[i] = szComponent[i];
        //}
        //to_narrow(szComponent, server_id, 256);
        printf("serid %s", server_id);
        //打印参数
        
    
        
    
        char* ret = ""; // 返回Http Response
        try
        {
            // 开始进行socket初始化
            WSADATA wData;  
            ::WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wData);  
    
            SOCKET clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, 1, 0);
            struct sockaddr_in ServerAddr = {0};
            char* m_ip = wchar2char(ipComponent);
            int m_port = atoi(wchar2char(portComponent));
    
            char* req = wchar2char(urlComponent);
            WCHAR bufchar[3069];
            //这里能正确打印出来自NSIS的中文信息。
            //wsprintf(bufchar, L"kagula $0=[%s][server_id]\n", char2wchar(server_id));
            //MessageBoxW(g_hwndParent, bufchar, 0, MB_OK);
            printf("req %s", req);
            char* urlSend = (char*) malloc(strlen(req) + strlen(server_id));
            strcpy(urlSend, req);
            strcat(urlSend, server_id);
            //strcat(req, server_id);
            printf("req %s", req);
            ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(m_ip);  
            ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(m_port);
            ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
            int errNo = connect(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)); 
            printf("errNo connect %d \n", errNo);
            if(errNo == 0)  
            {  
                //  "GET /[req] HTTP/1.1\r\n"  
                //  "Connection:Keep-Alive\r\n"
                //  "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate\r\n"  
                //  "Accept-Language:zh-CN,en,*\r\n"
                //  "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0\r\n\r\n";
                char* cookie = " HTTP/1.1\r\nCookie:16888\r\n\r\n";
                // strSend = "GET " + req + strSend;
                char* gp = "GET ";
    
                char* strSend = (char*) malloc(strlen(gp) + strlen(cookie) + strlen(urlSend));
                strcpy(strSend, gp);
                strcat(strSend, urlSend);
                strcat(strSend, cookie);
    
                // 发送
                errNo = send(clientSocket, strSend, strlen(strSend), 0);
                if(errNo > 0)  
                {  
                    //cout << "发送成功" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    //std::cout << "errNo:" << errNo << std::endl;
                    printf("errNo:");
                    // return ret;
                }
    
                // 接收
                char bufRecv[3069] = {0};
                errNo = recv(clientSocket, bufRecv, 3069, 0);
                if(errNo > 0)  
                {  
                    ret = bufRecv;// 如果接收成功，则返回接收的数据内容  
                }
                else
                {
                    // std::cout << "errNo:" << errNo << std::endl;
                    printf("errNo:");
                    // return ret;
                }
            }  
            else  
            {  
                errNo = WSAGetLastError();  
                // std::cout << "errNo:" << errNo << std::endl;
                printf("errNo:");
                printf(errNo + "");
            }  
            // socket环境清理
            ::WSACleanup();  
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // return "";
        }
        printf(ret);
    
     
        // push back on the stack
    
        TCHAR * tchar;
    
        char* ok_str = "ServerId is OK";
        if(strstr(ret, ok_str) == NULL) {
            tchar = _T("0");
        } else {
            tchar = _T("1");
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            printf("%d", i);
            szComponent[i] += 1;
        }
        pushstring(tchar);
        
    }
```

Comment: Change the runtime library to static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess the reason is the libraries like "ws2_32.lib" is not bundled in the package.

No, that thing is only consumed by Visual C++ linker. In runtime, the corresponding DLL is taken from `C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll`

Most likely reason is C and C++ runtime DLLs. By default, Visual Studio C++ projects use dynamic linking to these libraries. For an installer plugin, a good way to fix is switch to static C++ runtime. Right click on the project, Configuration properties, C/C++, Code Generation, change the “Runtime Library” setting to `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)` for debug configuration and `Multi-threaded (/MT)` for release configuration.

P.S. I would recommend a higher-level library for HTTP networking, such as WinHTTP or WinINet. Modern Internet has migrated from http to https.